# Wordpress File Uploader Error in Godaddy Managed WP Hosting

Tags: wordpress, file-upload, hosting

I am in a really interesting situation right now.

After migrating a client website from a development environment using, WP Clone by WP Academy, I get this error when trying to upload images via the Worpress media uploader.

> “image.png” has failed to upload due to an error
>   Unable to create directory uploads/2015/07. Is its parent directory writable by the server?

I logged into Godaddy and change the entire uploads/ folder permission via ssh to 777 (crazy enough). And all its contents.

I still got the same error.

After probing a little deeper, I found out the website is running from a different location than the machine i am sshed into.
What do I mean?

When I run pwd via ssh, to see my current working directory I get.

```
-bash-4.2$ pwd
/home/clientname/html/wp-content/uploads
```

But In the Wordpress setting at, Settings -> Media 
The  option "store uploads in this folder" has a value of

```
/home4/d***71/public_html/website.url/wp-content/uploads
```

Meaning The site files are copied and hosted in a different location than that given via the SSH,  This is probably due to the fact that Godaddy's managed wordpress hosting has some special cache setting configured beyond the control of the user.

The problem now is how do I correct the File Permission issue and have my uploads working properly.

:)

Comment: This problem has been solved by Godaddy Support team, Apparently there was a mistake in the Uploads directory location... Maybe cause by the migration from one server to another.

Answer (score 1):

1. login into your godaddy panel and click file manager
2. click or open your project folder
3. locate upload folder and click on check box
4. click into the privacy icon and check inherit an SET ALL SUB FOLDERS TO INHERIT PERMISSIONS both checkboxes

Answer (score 1):

I am just adding this, if anyone ran into the same issue in future.

1. Log into your GoDaddy account.
2. Go to the **Hosting page**.
3. Click **Manage**
4. Select **File Manager** for the domain you want to edit the permission *(this is, if you have multiple domains)*
5. Navigate to the folder where you have installed the WordPress.
6. Hover on the '**wp-content**' and you should able to see an arrow, click to see the option called '*Change Permissions*'.
7. You should able to see all the Permission details in this window.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The "Hover" didn't work for me. What DID work was to go to the directory above, put ONE check in a box for a DIRECTORY (not a file), and then click on "Privacy".

GoDaddy Permissions

[image]

If you check more than one folder, OR a file, you won't get the permissions eyeball to light up.

So, to fix a file permission you would have to go to the level above, and change "Set all subfolders to inherit permissions".

Apparently you can't change some files and not others - just the parent folder, which then sets all the files (is my guess).

This is NOT a limitation of Windows, it's the broken way they establish permissions.

Anyway - hopefully that will work. Tech support confirmed the drop down doesn't work anymore.

== John ==