# Wordpress - can't update to latest version

Tags: php, wordpress

I have wordpress installed through godaddy on a linux hosting account. Recently upgraded to php version 5.6 and the site still works. I'm currently logged in as the admin as well. When I go to update in wordpress dashboard, I get the following error:

Update WordPress
Downloading update from [https://downloads.wordpress.org/release/wordpress-5.7.1-new-bundled.zip…](https://downloads.wordpress.org/release/wordpress-5.7.1-new-bundled.zip%E2%80%A6)

Unpacking the update…

Verifying the unpacked files…

Preparing to install the latest version…

The update cannot be installed because we will be unable to copy some files. This is usually due to inconsistent file permissions.: wp-admin/setup-config.php

Installation Failed

Comment: See the various answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/31644047/231316

Comment: This is mostly due to wrong file permissions on your server. We have a good post about this on our blog https://www.wprulz.com/cant-update-wordpress-due-to-inconsistent-file-permissions/

Comment: Thanks! It was the file permissions on the godaddy hosting for that file.